# In GWT 2.0 CssResource, how I can turn off obfuscation for all my css classes?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, cssresource, clientbundle

I have a CssResource where I want to have some of the css classes "mapped" to methods:

```
@ClassName("top-table")
String topTable();
```

But I want to turn off the obfuscation GWT does (while developing at least, for better debugging in firebug, etc).

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I know I can use @external in my css file but then I have to define all my css classes like @external .c1, .c2, .c3, etc...

Something like @external .* would solve my problem but that doesn't seem to be available at least in gwt 2.0.x

My current solution is to use:

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty"/>
```

But that doesn't turn off the obfuscation, just makes it prettier :) I know obf is needed to avoid collisions but I don't have that in my case and would really like to turn off obfuscation

Comment: Where exactly did you put that line `<set-configuraion-property>`?

Comment: This should be reopened as the linked q&a was created after my initial question and my question contains more and better answers... Doesn't make sense to close the older question as duplicate....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the GWT documentation it is possible to disable ofbuscation in general. From [CssResource section "levers and knobs"](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#Levers_and_Knobs):

> The configuration property CssResource.style may be set to pretty
>   which will disable class-name obfuscation as well as pretty-print the
>   CSS content. Combine this with a ClientBundle.enableInlining value of
>   false to produce a CSS expression which is amenable to client-side
>   editing.

In my work GWT project, I can see this property is actually set in Resources.gwt.xml (included in gwt-user.jar):

```
  <!-- This can be used to make CssResource produce human-readable CSS -->
  <define-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" is-multi-valued="false" />
  <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="obf" />
```

What is unclear to me is how to override this value, since it is already set. Did you manage to figure that out?

Answer (score 6):

To disable obfuscation for all of you legacy classes at once, you can exploit what is said [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#External_and_legacy_scopes)

In short, in the legacy css file, which you are binding using CssResource bundle, put this declaration: `@external .*;`

All the classes in the file that has this declaration file will not be obfuscated.

Answer (score 2):

To have not obfuscated class names you simply need to add following line to your gwt.xml file:

```
  <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="stable" />
```

When set to stable class names will consist of qualified class name followed by method name in your resource interfaces (of course with all . replaced by _)

All possible values for CssResource.style (for gwt 2.7) are:

- pretty
- debug
- stable
- stable-shorttype
- stable-notype

To verify values available for your gwt version look at *com.google.gwt.resources.rg.CssObfuscationStyle* javadoc (or source code) for gwt version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`@external` directive](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#External_and_legacy_scopes) to prevent a css classname from being obfuscated.

In your case, your css file might contain

```
@external top-table;
.top-table {
  some: rule;
}
```

Comment: "Is there an easy way to achieve this? I know I can use @external in my css file but then I have to define all my css classes like @external .c1, .c2, .c3, etc..." Doing that for all classes is too time-consuming :(