# In GWT 2.0 CssResource, how I can turn off obfuscation for all classes in just one CssResource

Tags: css, gwt

I know that obfuscation can be turned off for ALL css resources ([In GWT 2.0 CssResource, how I can turn off obfuscation for all my css classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5972296/151365)) or for ONE external class (using @external)

**How can I turn off CSSResource obfuscation for only one type**. I want to use some Twitter Bootstrap, and they use [advanced attributed selectors](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attributeAdvanced.html) from CSS3. The only way I can think to get these to work is disable CSS obfuscation.

**Naturally**, I could avoid using a CssResource, but I like the handy tab-completion and static analysis that it does.

Any ideas? This doesn't work:

```
<when-type-is class="my.org.CssResource">
    <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty"/>
</when-type-is>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own question because it was hard to find:

By checking out the source-code, and cross comparing with the [GWT wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#Levers_and_Knobs), I found:

```
/* @external also accepts tail-globs */
@external .myProject-*;
.myProject-text {}
.myProject-foo {}
```

So, if you want to let all the classes in a CSS resources in a file be external, use:

```
@external *;
```